# Encoding error in reading non-latin characters from pdf file

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, pdfbox

I am trying to read Greek from a pdf file using PDFbox 1.8.7. The issue is that whatever encoding I use (Windows-1253, ISO-8859-7,UTF-8) I cannot read the greek characters. Could you provide me with an insight on what I need to set differently in the options of PDFbox in order to read the greek characters. (sample pdf file here https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/861b3c85bb2b1eca9f10af210a8eff4820141111223938/83ff55)

My source code is the following:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFText2HTML;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

    /**
     *
     * @author Administrator
     */
    public class Pdf {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
                PDDocument pdDoc = null;
                COSDocument cosDoc = null;
                File file = new File("C:\\themis\\Pdfs\\first.pdf");

                PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
                parser.parse();
                cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
                pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
                String encoding="ISO-8859-7";

                pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper(encoding);
                pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
                pdfStripper.setEndPage(2);
                String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
                System.out.println(parsedText);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PdfBMW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PdfBMW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please mention what version you are using (hopefully 1.8.7), and upload the greek pdf file somewhere. Please check that you can copy & paste the greek characters from Adobe Reader.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr yes I'm using 1.8.7. I have uploaded a sample pdf file in the question's description above. I can copy the characters but when I paste them, they do not show up as they are supposed to.

Comment: The font encoding contains a GID mapping -- that is, the indexes you get for 'characters' directly point to a *glyph* in the enclosed font, rather than a Unicode. Therefore, there is no link "back" from the encoded value to Greek characters. The English text appears as usual because it uses the same font but with the regular WinAnsiEncoding.

Comment: @Themis: in other words: your problem can't be solved this way. You'll have to use OCR :-(

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : thought so...let's see how it goes with OCR...